# D3.js and my sql : import and visualise data

Tags: javascript, mysql, d3.js, graph, cytoscape.js

i m working on a project to visualise a network on a php page using D3.js or cytoscape.js 
but i don t know how to import data from mysql .

any ideas ? or should i look for an other library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what library you're using.  You need to have an HTTP server running that accesses the DB.

If you use Cytoscape, you can just `fetch()` the results, e.g. `cytoscape({ elements: fetch('http://myserver/get-eles') })`

Comment: thanks . i  m trying actually to load the data from a json object generated with json_encode  , and cytoscape is taking all elements for nodes ,

Comment: Make sure to follow the proper format http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json